# generating code from XSD

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, spring-ws

I am using JAXB plugin to generated java code from XSD. One element is any:

```
<xs:complexType name="element">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="lax" namespace="##any"/>
        </xs:sequence
</xs:complexType>
```

so now when it generated java code there is :

```
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link Object }
 *     {@link Element }
```

but when I wanna convert to element it thrown exception that it is JAXBElement not element
can you help me ?
thx hudi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corresponding to the [JAXB FAQ](http://jaxb.java.net/faq/index.html#dom_bind) you can get three different result values:

1. JAXBElements
2. classes that are annotated with XmlRootElement
3. DOM elements

Therefore, you have to check the runtime type of the returned value.